# How to bind an models attribute to the views class

Tags: data-binding, ember.js, handlebars.js

Docs here:

http://emberjs.com/guides/views/customizing-a-views-element/

Discuss binding a class name to a true/false value in the view.
Is there a way to bind one of my models attributes to the view class name?

For example

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    name:  DS.attr('string'),
    type: DS.attr('string'),  // The loaded model could have a type of 'typeA' or 'typeB'
});

App.CategoryView = Ember.View.extend({
   classNameBindings: ['type'],
   type: function(){
       return this.model.get('type'); // This doesn't work obviously
   },
   tagName: 'li'
});
```

Would render

```
<li class="typeA"> [template_contents_are_here] </li>
```

edit: Using Ember 1.0rc

## edit 2

So I've got a little further and can now return a value from my function. However it only returns the correct value on my first iteration. I have a series of models being loaded from the server, each of which are being rendered using the {{control}} helper (therefore creating a new view and controller for each rendering)

```
App.CategoryView = Ember.View.extend({
       classNameBindings: ['type'],
       type: function(){
           return this.controller.get('model.type');
       }.property()
       tagName: 'li'
   });
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Will do. Can you link me to a fiddle with a working version of ember rc1, for me to fork? I've looked at a few and none of them seem to work. EDIT: Nevermind - found one: http://jsfiddle.net/odigity/MXBsK/

Comment: You can also find jsfiddles/jsbins in the 'Reporting a Bug' section here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: this might be related: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1990

Comment: @Wildhoney Took a while but here goes: http://jsfiddle.net/hutYc/6/

Comment: @c4p Thanks. I'd seen that one already and had to use the fix on that thread in order to get my tree rendering code to work. You're right that it may be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/hutYc/8/

When you define a computed property, you need to declare what properties it depends upon:

```
App.CategoryView = Ember.View.extend({
   classNameBindings: ['type'],
   type: function(){
       return this.get('context.type');
   }.property("context.type"),
   tagName: 'li'
});
```

**Note** I replaced your way of access to the type attribute with a more 'emberish' way of doing this. A view should always work upon its context.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it might have to do with some sort of race condition. Is the view being created before the model is bound to the controller?

Comment: First the view is created. I guess then the property is calculated and gets cached (computed properties get cached). Afterwards the controller/model is connected to the view.